# WPF Ellipse why can I not add a grid?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application. I am trying to create a ellipse toggle button. I wanted to have a textbox in the ellipse with two images next to each other below the textbox. In my other buttons I have added a grid with two rows to achieve this.

However it doesn't like it when I try to add a grid to an ellipse. "The type ellipse does not support direct content". What does this mean? Is it possible to do what I wish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This particular error really couldn't be too much clearer:

> The type `Ellipse` does not support direct content.

The `Ellipse Shape` is *not* a `ContentControl`. Therefore, it does *not* have a `Content` property. This means that you *cannot* add any content to it.

What you *can* do is to add a `Grid` with no columns or rows defined and add your `Ellipse` into the `Grid`. Then you can overlay other UI elements *in front of* the `Ellipse`, which may *appear* as if they were inside it.

Comment: so is there no way of adding an image or text to an ellipse shape?